# AVRecorder can't set bit depth

Tags: ios

I'm trying to control the bit depth of a .m4a file recorded with AVRecorder :

```
NSDictionary *settings =  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0],                 AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 8],         AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey,
                          nil];
```

But `AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey` has no effect, same for `AVEncoderAudioQualityKey`.

It seems that iOS7 and 8 have different defaults : iOS7 always gives a s16p format (according to ffmpeg) and iOS8 a s32p.

I don't want to use any other format than AppleLossless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `AVEncoderAudioQualityKey` is applicable to `kAudioFormatAppleLossless` and `AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey` *is* only a hint.

Maybe you'd have more luck getting 8bit audio in ALAC via the lower level CoreAudio `AudioConverter` API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you explain what a "hint" does exactly in this case ?

Comment: It's something the encoder could use, or completely ignore, as is happening in your case